# Смысл поговорки "не по чину нос"

Tags: фраза

Что имеется в виду в старой русской поговорке "Не по чину нос"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Не по чину нос* = *Не по чину подношение (взятка)*, т.е. "слишком много хочешь", "не по чину берёшь", "это не для тебя" и т.п.

Противоположное значение имеет всем известное *остаться с носом*, т.е. твое "подношение" никто и брать-то не стал.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Синоним "всяк сверчок знай свой шесток", "каждому - свое", или "знай свое место".

С происхождением поговорки не могу помочь.

Comment: Спасибо, maxkoryukov!